# Excel VBA assignment & I am not able to obtain the color of fruits/ vegetables and herbs after setting up the input boxes

Tags: excel, vba

Q: Create a sub procedure, named “Task2”, to obtain the font colors and interior color using input box functions. Allow user to enter the colors of “Fruits” and “Vegetables” using 2 input box functions respectively. Use another input box function to obtain the interior color of herbs. Then use If/Then/ElseIf structure to change the font and interior colors based on the user’s inputs. There is no need to create message box in this sub.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim FruitColor As Variant
Dim VegColor As Variant
Dim HerbColor As Variant

' create 3 input box functions here to obtain user's preference:
' 2 input box functions for Fruits (Blue or Magenta), and
' Vegetables (Red or Cyan); 1 input box function for interior
' color of Herbs (Yellow or Green)

FruitColor = InputBox("Please enter the color of fruits: " & vbCrLf & _
"Blue or Magenta", "Fruit Color")

If FruitColor = "Blue" Then
    FruitColor = vbBlue
Else
    FruitColor = vbMagenta
End If


' insert If/Then/Else structures to format the colors of
' Vegetables and Herbs

VegColor = InputBox("Please enter the color of vegetables: " & vbCrLf & _
"Red or Cyan", "Vegetables Color")

If VegColor = "Red" Then
    VegColor = vbRed
Else
    VegColor = vbCyan
End If

HerbColor = InputBox("Please enter the interior color of herbs: " & vbCrLf & _
"Yellow or Green", "Herbs Color")

If HerbColor = "Red" Then
    HerbColor = vbYellow
Else
    HerbColor = vbGreen
End If


With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To RowCount
        ' insert the IF/THEN/ELSE structure here to
        ' format the font color of Fruits and Vegetables,
        ' and interior color of Herbs


    Next
End With
```

[How sheet1 looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4BCF.png)

Comment: You need to describe the exact problem you're having.  What happens when you run your code, and how is it different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: What does the data on `Sheet1` look like? What `If` statements have you tried?